# Pointer to 2D array solution produce warnings

Tags: keil

On Keil C51 compiler using an already posted solution I get the following warning

Mail.c(256): warning C182: pointer to different objects

on "pointer = &tab1;"

```
int (*pointer)[100][280]; // pointer creation
pointer = &tab1; //assignation
(*pointer)[5][12] = 517; // use
int myint = (*pointer)[5][12]; // use
```

OK here is my exact code, nothing i do seems to cure the problem...could it be the data space that objects are in??

```
int xdata RefPSX [PSX_SIZE][NUMBER_VOLTS]; //xdata space

int (xdata * xdata Ptr)[PSX_SIZE][NUMBER_VOLTS]; //pointer in xdta space pointing //to xdata 2D array

Ptr=RefPSX; // init pointer ****warning C182: pointer different objects****

(*Ptr)[1][2] = 4; // use
```

Why the warning... the code works but why?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If tab is declared like this:

```
int tab1[100][280];
```

then tab1 is already a pointer, so assignation should be:

```
pointer = tab1;
```

But in fact you could specify your question more.

Comment: Thanks, I think my problem may be to do with the data space the objects are in.  int xdata tab1[100][280];

Comment: int xdata RefPSX  [PSX_SIZE][NUMBER_VOLTS]; //xdata space

int  (xdata * xdata Ptr)[PSX_SIZE][NUMBER_VOLTS]; //pointer in xdta space pointing to xdata 2D array

Ptr=RefPSX;  // init pointer ****warning C182: pointer to different objects****

(*Ptr)[1][2] = 4; // use